# Como obtener el id de un un grupo de botones con JS?

Tags: javascript, html

Buen dia,

Ando creando un simple proyecto donde tengo un grupo de 9 botones. Estoy programando un js script que al momento de dar click en cualquiera de los 9 botones, les cambie el valor asignado a este boton.

Mi problema recide en que no se como obtener el valor del boton que selecciono en ese momento sin tener que crear un funcion para cada boton.

```
 <div class="lineas">                  
                <button type="button" id="b1" class="cajas" onclick="asignar(this)"> ? </button>
                <button type="button" id="b2" class="cajas" onclick="asignar(this)"> ? </button>
                <button type="button" id="b3" class="cajas" onclick="asignar(this)"> ? </button><br/>
                <button type="button" id="b4" class="cajas" onclick="asignar(this)"> ? </button>
                <button type="button" id="b5" class="cajas" onclick="asignar(this)"> ? </button>
                <button type="button" id="b6" class="cajas" onclick="asignar(this)"> ? </button> <br/>
                <button type="button" id="b7" class="cajas" onclick="asignar(this)"> ? </button>
                <button type="button" id="b8" class="cajas" onclick="asignar(this)"> ? </button>
                <button type="button" id="b9" class="cajas" onclick="asignar(this)"> ? </button>           
            </div>
```

Y este de abajo seria mi funcion, donde esperaba que recibiera un valor

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function asignar(comp) {
            let id = comp.id;
            var uno = document.getElementById(id);
            valor ? uno.innerText = "X" : uno.innerText = "?";
            valor ? uno.innerText = "O" : uno.innerText = "X";
            valor = !valor
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: el boton trae por defecto un valor "?", la validacion abajo lo que haria es si el valor es ? entonces le asigne una X, si es una X entonces asigne una O. La validacion si funciona por que la probe con un solo boton.

Answer (score 1):

La variable `comp` contiene el boton seleccionado (ha sido llamado como `asignar(this)` y en este caso `this` es el boton en si.

```js
function asignar(comp) {
    var valor = comp.innerText.trim();
    if (valor == '?') comp.innerText = "X";
    if (valor == 'X') comp.innerText = "O" ;
    if (valor == 'O') comp.innerText = "?" ;
    //console.log(valor);
}
```

```html
<div class="lineas">                  
  <button type="button" id="b1" class="cajas" onclick="asignar(this)"> ? </button>
  <button type="button" id="b2" class="cajas" onclick="asignar(this)"> ? </button>
  <button type="button" id="b3" class="cajas" onclick="asignar(this)"> ? </button><br/>
  <button type="button" id="b4" class="cajas" onclick="asignar(this)"> ? </button>
  <button type="button" id="b5" class="cajas" onclick="asignar(this)"> ? </button>
  <button type="button" id="b6" class="cajas" onclick="asignar(this)"> ? </button> <br/>
  <button type="button" id="b7" class="cajas" onclick="asignar(this)"> ? </button>
  <button type="button" id="b8" class="cajas" onclick="asignar(this)"> ? </button>
  <button type="button" id="b9" class="cajas" onclick="asignar(this)"> ? </button>           
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

La solucion fue la siguiente,

```
    <ui:composition template="./plantilla/plantilla1.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
            <h1 class="encabezados"> Juguemos Gato!</h1>
            <div class="contenedor">                  
                <button type="button" id="b1" class="cajas" > . </button>
                <button type="button" id="b2" class="cajas" > . </button>
                <button type="button" id="b3" class="cajas" > . </button><br/>
                <button type="button" id="b4" class="cajas" > . </button>
                <button type="button" id="b5" class="cajas" > . </button>
                <button type="button" id="b6" class="cajas" > . </button> <br/>
                <button type="button" id="b7" class="cajas" > . </button>
                <button type="button" id="b8" class="cajas" > . </button>
                <button type="button" id="b9" class="cajas" > . </button>           
            </div>           
            <h2 class="encabezados" id="status" > Aun no hay un ganador</h2>
            
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>


    <script>//script para turnar entre x y o en los botones de gato
        var valor = true;
        const contenedor = document.querySelector('.contenedor'); //variable contrante para la clase
        contenedor.addEventListener('click', (elemento) => { //agregar un evenlistener de tipo click
            if (elemento.target.classList.value === 'cajas') { //todo aquel elemento que posea la clase cajas entra en esta condicion
                console.log(elemento.target.id);
                valor ? elemento.target.innerText = "X" : elemento.target.innerText = " ";
                valor ? elemento.target.innerText = "O" : elemento.target.innerText = "X";
                valor = !valor;
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```